# Or in a Elasticsearch filter

Tags: python, apache, python-3.x, elasticsearch

I want to query my elasticsearch (using a python library) and I want to filter some of the document. Since I don't want to have a score I'm using only filter and must not keyword:

```
{
        "_source": ["entities"], 
        "query": {
            "bool": {
                "must_not": [
                  {"exists": {"field": "retweeted_status"}}
                ],
                "filter": [
                  {"match": {"entities.urls.display_url": "blabla.com"}},
                  {"match": {"entities.urls.display_url": "blibli.com"}}]
            }
        }
    }
```

This is the query I have done but the problem is that in the same filter it's apparently a `AND` operation that is effectued. I would like it to be a OR. How can I change my query to have all the document that contain "blibli.com" OR "blabla.com"

Comment: Try if [`should`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-bool-query.html) instead of `filter` gives you the desired result.

Comment: @Pit should will imply a scoring in my query and I don't want to slow it down

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can nest `bool` inside another `bool` so you can write query like this:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must_not": [
        {
          "exists": {
            "field": "retweeted_status"
          }
        }
      ],
      "filter": [
        {
          "bool": {
            "should": [
              {
                "match": {
                  "entities.urls.display_url": "blabla.com"
                }
              },
              {
                "match": {
                  "entities.urls.display_url": "blibli.com"
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Tested on ES 5.3, you can use [Explain API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-explain.html) to check if this also works in your version of Elasticsearch.